# Using KCFinder with Laravel 4

Tags: laravel

Can somebody please guide me how to use KCFinder in L4?
Where should I place the downloaded KCFinder and what changes should I make?

I cannot make it what this means:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
// ...
   config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
   config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
// ...
};
```

Also, to set sessions, I found this:

> https://gist.github.com/frzsombor/ddd0e11f93885060ef35

But I could not make out where to put package first. Should I place this in public directory? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4.2

In your view page, put the below code

```
<textarea name="ckeditor_id" id="ckeditor_id" ></textarea>
```

Below is my path where i had put my plugin `kcfinder` folder

```
{{ URL::asset('/theme/metronic_one_v_4/global/plugins/kcfinder/') }}
```

then

```
CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor_id', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl:"{{ URL::asset('/your_path_upto_plugin/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files') }}",
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl:"{{ URL::asset('/your_path_upto_plugin/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images') }}",
    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl:"    {{ URL::asset('/your_path_upto_plugin/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash') }}",
    filebrowserUploadUrl:"{{ URL::asset('/your_path_upto_plugin/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files') }}",
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl:"{{ URL::asset('/your_path_upto_plugin/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images') }}",
    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl:"{{ URL::asset('/your_path_upto_plugin/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash') }}",        
});
```

And go to

`kcfinder/conf/config.php`

```
// GENERAL SETTINGS

'disabled' => false, <- set disable "false" Instade of "true"
'uploadURL' => "upload",
'uploadDir' => "",
'theme' => "default",
```

Your plugin will work now